# Creating JAR files programmatically - Adding files to specific folder inside jar

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to create a JAR file programmatically as one of the feature of our product. I am using below code to achieve:

```
        //Assume all necessary imports and variables are declared
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(jarFilePath);

        Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");

        JarOutputStream jarOut = null;
        FileInputStream reader = null;

        for(String pathToJava:pathToJavaFile) {
            jarOut = new JarOutputStream(fOut,manifest);
            reader = new FileInputStream(pathToJava);
            jarOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(pathToJava));
        }

        while ((readCount = reader.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) >= 0) {
            if(readCount > 0) {
                jarOut.write(buffer,0,readCount);
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly and I am able to create jar file. The problem lies in this line:
`jarOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(pathToJava));` assume if `pathToJava` is having a value like `c:/foo/bar/FooBar.java`, it is creating a folders inside jar file like `c: --> foo --> bar` and then putting FooBar.java inside it. What I want is I should be able to put that `FooBar.java` inside specific folder like `sources`?

Is there anyway I can configure `JarOutputStream` to put files in specific folder? Or Do I have any other options to look for? I can programmatically use `java -jar` but I am stepping back because complexity in finding  whether user has installed jdk or not. Can anyone guide me in this?

Comment: dummy question: did you try to create your own desired pathToJava, e.g. `jarOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("sources/foo/bar/FoorBar.java"))`? it's just an idea, never tried it.

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths to reference your files?

Comment: @EricStein, user will choose the location from UI, so I will not know location upfront.

Comment: FWITW, I see 3 bugs in the OP's code. jarOut should be declared outside the for loop. for loop should close after while loop and jarOut should be closed.

Comment: @PradeepSimha have you found any answer? I need the same answer.